# ifstream does not completely read whole data

Tags: c++, byte, ifstream

I'm trying to read a file block by block. Blocksize is 64Byte. But some bytes are left.

Example: I have a 360 Byte file and read the data in 64byte blocks, so I need 6 times a 64 byteblock to get all data.

```
typedef unsigned char uint1;

ifstream is(path.c_str(), ifstream::in | ifstream::binary);
uint1 data[64];
int i = 0;

while (is.read((char*)data, 64)) {        
    i++;
}

cout << i << endl;
```

But I only get 5 times a completely filled 64-Byte Block. How to get the remaining Bytes??

Comment: what is the value of "i" at the end?

Comment: the value of "i" is 5 at the end

Comment: special thx to ValeryShevchuk and Angew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

360 is not divisible by 64, which means that the last block will not be read in its entirety. Consulting [suitable documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) shows that reading such an incomplete block sets both `eofbit` and `failbit` on the stream from which you're reading, which means the condition in your `while` loop will evaluate to `false` for the last block. But the read *did* actually happen and *the data is stored correctly.*

You might want to check the value of [`gcount()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/gcount) after the last read:

```
while (is.read((char*)data, 64)) {        
    i++;
}
if (is.gcount() > 0) {
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I suppose the problem is your file size is not divisible by buffer size, so last chunk's size is less than 64(360 - 64 * 5 = 40 bytes). And for this case doc for [istream::read](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/) says:

> If the input sequence runs out of characters to extract (i.e., the end-of-file is reached) before n characters have been successfully read, the array pointed to by s contains all the characters read until that point, and both the eofbit and failbit flags are set for the stream.

So, last is.read's return value is evaluated to "false" and it's not counted by your counter.

Comment: Yes, I know that. Is there no simple way to load the data of a file into blocks?

Comment: @tbol, your last block is loaded correctly, but you must check how many bytes were read from stream using "istream::gcount", so you may safely use first istream::gcount() bytes in your "data" array

Comment: Thx a lot, the bytes are definitively stored.

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is actually to read the file, and not simply to count the number of blocks as your sample does then you probably want smth like this:

```
std::ifstream is( path.c_str(), std::ios_base::binary ); // in mode is always set for ifstream 

if( !is )
  throw std::runtime_error("unable to open file '" + path + "'" ); 

while( !is.eof() )
{
  std::array< char, 64 > buf;        
  is.peek(); // needs this because of the buffering.
  const auto n = is.readsome( buf.data(), buf.size() );
  if( is )
    handle_block( buf, n ); // std::cout.write( buf.data(), n )
  else
    throw std::runtime_error("error reading file '" + path + "'" ); 
}
```

Comment: My aim is to read bytes from the file and I've used the counter to get a response whether the reading was successfull or not. I only forgot to check out if the last byte block was really read. So thx for your help but I already have a solution for reading bytes right now.